# ros_canopen homing simultaneously or one-by-one?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

this question has been addressed in these questions as well ([Q1](http://answers.ros.org/question/284879/simultaneous-homing-in-ros-canopen/), [Q2](http://answers.ros.org/question/314874/homing-all-motors-simultaneously-in-ros-canopen/)), however no answer arrived, therefore i'm asking as well.

It is not clear from the wiki of [ros_canopen](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_402?distro=kinetic) that how does the node execute the homing of multiple motors/joints?

Do the motors execute the homing simultaneously or one-by-one?

If one-by-one, than does it mean, that the execution of the next homing procedure is not started until the previous has not been finished?

Also, is it possible to change the order of the sequence? I mean, what if i want to execute the homing like, joint1-joint3-joint2-joint4-joint5? Should be enough just to change the order in the `yaml` config file?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326567/ros_canopen-homing-simultaneously-or-one-by-one?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Do the motors execute the homing simultaneously or one-by-one?

One-by-one (`canopen_motor_node`, as-is).

> If one-by-one, than does it mean, that the execution of the next homing procedure is not started until the previous has not been finished?

Exactly

> Also, is it possible to change the order of the sequence? I mean, what if i want to execute the homing like, joint1-joint3-joint2-joint4-joint5?

Yes, just use [list syntax](http://wiki.ros.org/canopen_chain_node#Node_layer) to specify the overall order

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1